# Android 3d Graphics library that supports shadow and reflection

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I've been digging since while for 3D graphics tutorials for Android. I tried raw opengl (es). I also tried min3d. I found out that things can be very complex or very easy if someone else did the math for you. Min3D is really great and easy to use, but is also really minimalistic. I can't find how to make lights actually cast shadows (and I doubt it's supported), I can't find how to make the surface reflect, how to change the surface to diffuse more or less.

Is there any library that has scene handling and supports shadows (also shadow cast by diffused light), control materials to achieve different levels of diffusion, reflections and transparency.

Note: I forgot to mention I need **free** framework.

Since the answer of Eric convinced me that realistic 3d is hard to achieve on mobile devices I would accept answers that explain how to fake these effects (or links). Again effects I need are:

- shadows
- reflections

  - from glossy material
  - from matte material
- transparency (I think that's in the min3d examples, but it's here for completeness

I've seen shadows in 3d android games, although I'm not 100% convinced that are real (cast by objects).

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any libraries that meet your requirements for a mobile platform, but there are several middleware products to choose from:

- Unity3d : http://unity3d.com/
- Unreal SDK : http://udk.com
- Ogre : http://www.ogre3d.org/

All of these offer scene management, lighting, material management, etc... yet, I doubt any of these are a silver bullet for what you are asking. Regardless of pricing and licensing - upto 3500 dollars for Unity3D pro mobile - you will still have to do a serious amount of coding yourself and often in a language you may not be familar with.

Also, keep in mind that a lot of the gfx in opengl-es based products (mostly games) are often faked. While it's perfectly possible to have dynamic lighting, shadows and transparency, these things can be crippling for your performance if you have a lot of geometry. After all, a phone or tablet is not the powerhouse that a desktop cpu/gpu is these days. Not yet anyway.

Another thing to note: I'm not sure what level of realism you are trying to achieve, but all the things you mention are typically associated with raytracing/raycasting. And that's a whole other bag of tricks as you can forget about real-time interaction, especially on mobile devices.

No way around it: coding and creating with real-time graphics in mind is hard and it's even harder on mobile platforms.

Comment: It is about a single sphere ... with a hole in it - the magic eight ball. Performance would not be a problem. Well. I guess I can fake the shadow of a sphere easily. Not sure how to make reflections. These frameworks/libs are a little bit more than I need. Still you made me think a little bit more about faking effects and I now have few ideas to try. However I think you are wrong about mobile devices - 1.5GHz quad core mobile cpus are already in the market. in few years mobile device with quad core cpu won't be that expensive.

Comment: I've used Blender for a long time now. There is only cheating. Nothing is real. It's pretty easy to fake shadows and reflections (as long as both are static) using textures and a reflection map (moving an image around depending on the angle of the camera vs the surface normal).